# Is it possible to use the symbology of an already published map service, so as to create a renderer in javascript api?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, symbology, feature-layer, map-service

I have created a map service with fixed symbology. 
I want to create a graphics layer which will use the same symbology, through a renderer. In other words, I want to use the already existing symbology which is contained in an another map layer (feature layer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the featureLayers renderer to JSON. Then use the JSON to create a new renderer.

```
var featureLayerRenderer = featureLayer.renderer.toJson();

var renderer = esri.renderer.fromJson(featureLayerRenderer);
```

Comment: Can this work with dynamic map layers?